# android convert "createAt" to date

Tags: android

I  have call server, return int of createAt, i want convert to date.

```
 @JsonProperty(FoursquareWebService.WS_API_JSON_FIELD_CREATEDAT)
    public int getCreatedAt() {
        return this.createdAt;
    }
```

Can you help me.

```
   SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM d, yyyy");    

            String date = format.format(new Date(item.getCreatedAt()));
            Log.e(">>>>>>>>>>CreateAt",
                  "" + item.getCreatedAt());
            Log.e(">>>>>>>>>>",
                  "" + date);
```

Result :

```
05-28 10:22:01.829  10593-10593/com.cc E/>>>>>>>>>>CreateAt﹕ 1363880768
05-28 10:22:01.829  10593-10593/com.cc E/>>>>>>>>>>﹕ Jan 16, 1970
```

**it's correct : Oct 3, 2012**

Comment: What you want to convert?

Comment: But you are already converting the date. What's the problem?

Comment: Result not correct. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, create a getDate() method

```
private String getDate(long timeStamp){

    try{
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM d, yyyy");
        Date netDate = (new Date(timeStamp));
        return sdf.format(netDate);
    }
    catch(Exception ex){
        return "xx";
    }
}
```

This method will accept a long argument. Convert your date to a long before using this method.

```
    int dateFromJson = item.getCreatedAt();
    String s = Integer.toString(dateFromJson);
    // Convert to milliseconds
    long timestamp = Long.parseLong(s) * 1000;
    Log.d("DATE", getDate(timestamp));
```

This gives your date as Mar 21, 2013. It is the correct result according to  [here](http://www.epochconverter.com/)

Answer (score 1):

Try to convert the String you become to Date like this:

```
String dtStart = item.getCreatedAt();  
SimpleDateFormat  format = new SimpleDateFormat("MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS"); //this is the format you become your date in 
try {  
    Date date = format.parse(dtStart);  
    System.out.println(date);  
} catch (ParseException e) {  
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block  
    e.printStackTrace();  
}
```

EDIT: Convert milliseconds to a date:

```
public static String getDate(long milliSeconds, String dateFormat){
    SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat(dateFormat);

    // Create a calendar object that will convert the date and time value in milliseconds to date. 
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.setTimeInMillis(milliSeconds);
    return formatter.format(calendar.getTime());
}
```

and then you can call the method for example like this:

```
System.out.println(getDate(item.getCreatedAt(), "MMM d, yyyy"));
```

Comment: sorry,but  debugs: W/System.err﹕ java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "1334766899" (at offset 10)

Comment: ops, my failure - I thought that your date is in the format at the beginning - take a look at my edit of the post

Comment: result : I/System.out﹕ Jan 16, 1970
but result correct: Oct 3, 2012.
Can you help me?

Comment: Actually something else is wrong with your code - this value in milliseconds returns exactly Jan 16, 1970, try it yourself here in this online converter and search for an exception in the code, where you become the date http://www.fileformat.info/tip/java/date2millis.htm Do you have another way to become the date that should be converted?

Comment: i call from server. you can see edit question of me.

Comment: Can you please try to change the declaration of your method from this `public int getCreatedAt() {` to this `public long getCreatedAt() {` - I mean, is it possible to be a bug from the variable type?